# Windows Batch script tp process flat files

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, flat

I want some help in writing Windows Batch Script.
I have a Delimeted Text file with data as shown below:

```
1|2|3|4|5|6
1|2|3|4|5|6
1|2|3|4|5|6
1|2|3|4|5|6
1|2|3|4|5|6
1|2|3|4|5|6.
```

I want to write a script where I can edit this Text file to remove the first and the last fields of the data.
So that the output text file would be containing data as :

```
2|3|4|5
2|3|4|5
2|3|4|5
2|3|4|5
2|3|4|5
2|3|4|5.
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vibhor

Comment: What is the period? Just an indicator of the end of file? or is it really a character in the file?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write a pure batch solution, but to write a robust solution that can handle anything you throw at it is quite tricky, and the final result will be slow.

It is quite easy to accomplish the task with JScript and regular expressions, but not everyone knows those technologies (although there are probably more that know JScript and regex than know batch!)

I have written a hybrid JScript/batch utility called REPL.BAT that is easily called from the command line or from a batch file. It performs regular expression search and replace on stdin and writes the result to stdout. It works on all modern versions of Windows, starting with XP.

Your task is easily and efficiently accomplished using REPL.BAT

Assuming every line has all 6 values (empty values OK, but always has 5 delimiters):

```
type test.txt|repl "^[^|]*\|(.*)\|[^|]*$" "$1" >test.txt.new
move /y test.txt.new test.txt
```

If some lines are missing values at the end (missing values assumed to be empty):

```
type test.txt|repl "(^[^|]*(\|[^|]*){4})\|[^|]*$" "$1"|repl "^[^|]*\|?(.*)$" "$1" >test.txt.new
move /y test.txt.new test.txt
```

Here is the REPL.BAT utility. It should be placed in the same folder as your batch script and file, or better yet placed in a folder that resides in your PATH. Full documentation is built into the script.

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* Harmless hybrid line that begins a JScript comment

::************ Documentation ***********
:::
:::REPL  Search  Replace  [Options  [SourceVar]]
:::REPL  /?
:::
:::  Performs a global search and replace operation on each line of input from
:::  stdin and prints the result to stdout.
:::
:::  Each parameter may be optionally enclosed by double quotes. The double
:::  quotes are not considered part of the argument. The quotes are required
:::  if the parameter contains a batch token delimiter like space, tab, comma,
:::  semicolon. The quotes should also be used if the argument contains a
:::  batch special character like &, |, etc. so that the special character
:::  does not need to be escaped with ^.
:::
:::  If called with a single argument of /? then prints help documentation
:::  to stdout.
:::
:::  Search  - By default this is a case sensitive JScript (ECMA) regular
:::            expression expressed as a string.
:::
:::            JScript regex syntax documentation is available at
:::            http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541(v=vs.80).aspx
:::
:::  Replace - By default this is the string to be used as a replacement for
:::            each found search expression. Full support is provided for
:::            substituion patterns available to the JScript replace method.
:::            A $ literal can be escaped as $$. An empty replacement string
:::            must be represented as "".
:::
:::            Replace substitution pattern syntax is documented at
:::            http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/efy6s3e6(v=vs.80).aspx
:::
:::  Options - An optional string of characters used to alter the behavior
:::            of REPL. The option characters are case insensitive, and may
:::            appear in any order.
:::
:::            I - Makes the search case-insensitive.
:::
:::            L - The Search is treated as a string literal instead of a
:::                regular expression. Also, all $ found in Replace are
:::                treated as $ literals.
:::
:::            B - The Search must match the beginning of a line.
:::                Mostly used with literal searches.
:::
:::            E - The Search must match the end of a line.
:::                Mostly used with literal searches.
:::
:::            V - Search and Replace represent the name of environment
:::                variables that contain the respective values. An undefined
:::                variable is treated as an empty string.
:::
:::            M - Multi-line mode. The entire contents of stdin is read and
:::                processed in one pass instead of line by line. ^ anchors
:::                the beginning of a line and $ anchors the end of a line.
:::
:::            X - Enables extended substitution pattern syntax with support
:::                for the following escape sequences:
:::
:::                \\     -  Backslash
:::                \b     -  Backspace
:::                \f     -  Formfeed
:::                \n     -  Newline
:::                \r     -  Carriage Return
:::                \t     -  Horizontal Tab
:::                \v     -  Vertical Tab
:::                \xnn   -  Ascii (Latin 1) character expressed as 2 hex digits
:::                \unnnn -  Unicode character expressed as 4 hex digits
:::
:::                Escape sequences are supported even when the L option is used.
:::
:::            S - The source is read from an environment variable instead of
:::                from stdin. The name of the source environment variable is
:::                specified in the next argument after the option string.
:::

::************ Batch portion ***********
@echo off
if .%2 equ . (
  if "%~1" equ "/?" (
    findstr "^:::" "%~f0" | cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" "^:::" ""
    exit /b 0
  ) else (
    call :err "Insufficient arguments"
    exit /b 1
  )
)
echo(%~3|findstr /i "[^SMILEBVX]" >nul && (
  call :err "Invalid option(s)"
  exit /b 1
)
cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*
exit /b 0

:err
>&2 echo ERROR: %~1. Use REPL /? to get help.
exit /b

************* JScript portion **********/
var env=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("Process");
var args=WScript.Arguments;
var search=args.Item(0);
var replace=args.Item(1);
var options="g";
if (args.length>2) {
  options+=args.Item(2).toLowerCase();
}
var multi=(options.indexOf("m")>=0);
var srcVar=(options.indexOf("s")>=0);
if (srcVar) {
  options=options.replace(/s/g,"");
}
if (options.indexOf("v")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/v/g,"");
  search=env(search);
  replace=env(replace);
}
if (options.indexOf("l")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/l/g,"");
  search=search.replace(/([.^$*+?()[{\\|])/g,"\\$1");
  replace=replace.replace(/\$/g,"$$$$");
}
if (options.indexOf("b")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/b/g,"");
  search="^"+search
}
if (options.indexOf("e")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/e/g,"");
  search=search+"$"
}
if (options.indexOf("x")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/x/g,"");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\\\/g,"\\B");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\b/g,"\b");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\f/g,"\f");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\n/g,"\n");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\r/g,"\r");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\t/g,"\t");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\v/g,"\v");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}/g,
    function($0,$1,$2){
      return String.fromCharCode(parseInt("0x"+$0.substring(2)));
    }
  );
  replace=replace.replace(/\\B/g,"\\");
}
var search=new RegExp(search,options);

if (srcVar) {
  WScript.Stdout.Write(env(args.Item(3)).replace(search,replace));
} else {
  while (!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream) {
    if (multi) {
      WScript.Stdout.Write(WScript.StdIn.ReadAll().replace(search,replace));
    } else {
      WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(WScript.StdIn.ReadLine().replace(search,replace));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `sed`  from [GnuWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)

```
sed "s/^1|//;s/|6//" file
```

or cmd shell:

```
for /f "tokens=2-6delims=|6" %a in (file) do @echo(%a^|%b^|%c^|%d%e
```